# Probability of taking balls from a bag

Tags: probability

I have a bag that contains balls:

1. 2 blue
2. 3 red
3. 1 white

ball.

My task is to calculate, what is the probability that after 3 rounds of taking bals, i still have no blue balls.

I am not sure if i translated it correctly, but:

P(1B) = probability that i take blue ball in first round

P(2B) = probability that i take blue ball in second round

and so on.

My task is to find $P(1M^{c}\cap{} 2M^{c}\cap3M^{c})$.

Now i know that 
$P(A^{1}\cap{} A^{2}\cap{}A^{3})$ = $P(A^{1}) * P(A^{2}| A^{1}) * P(A^{3}| A^{1}
\cap{} A^{2})$

However in my case i would have to write a lot of things:

$P(1M^{c}) = 4/6$

$P(2M^{c} | 1M^{c})$ = $\frac{P(1M^{c}\cap{}2M^{c})}{1M^{c}}$

$P(1M^{c}\cap{}2M^{c})$ have 3 combinations = (red,red),(red,white),(white,red)

and if i wanted to calculate

$P(3M^{c} | 1M^{c} \cap{} 2M^{c})$ i would have also  (red,red,red,),(red,red,white),(red,white,red),(white,red,red)

So far we have 3 combinations, and lot of calculations, how could i find the probability more intuitive? or with some trick, am i missing something?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probability is given by
$$\frac{4*3*2}{6*5*4}=\frac{1}{5}=0.2$$
Where the numerators are the number of balls we can select each time and the denominators are the number of balls left in the bag.

Comment: ok but how did u get to this calculation?

Comment: The probability of not selecting blue on the first try is $\frac{4}{6}$ as $4$ out of the $6$ balls are not blue. On the next draw, there are $5$ balls left and $3$ of them are not blue, so the probability of not selecting blue is then $\frac{3}{5}$. On the last draw, the probability of not selecting blue is then similarly $\frac{2}{4}$. The probability of all of these events occuring simultaneously is then $\frac{1}{5}$ - the product of all of the previous probabilities as all of the events occur independently. Any other scenario involves selecting a blue ball, so is not included.